# Repository Pattern with NPoco, Worth it?

Tags: c#, architecture, repository-pattern, petapoco, npoco

I am considering NPoco for a large business application. I am a bit concerned that is it worth to develop a repository pattern?

I will need to handle complex SQL statements and extensive database operations on several entities in a same use case.

NPoco provides a variety of db operations functions, which I think will not be (directly) exposed to the consumer layer(s) by my repository layer.

Edit-1
Which approach is better to get most out of NPoco?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invest time in unit tests, then the Repository Pattern is worth it. However if most of your application logic is in stored procs and functions, then you will be limited with unit tests and just spend your time in integration testing.

Comment: in my case, business logic is not in db stored procedures/functions and will be the responsibility of the services layer.